# Printing UTF-8 QR-Codes shows special characters for Umlauts

Tags: qr-code, listlabel

I am trying to use List & Label in my C# application to output a QR code in UTF-8 encoding. This is exactly what my customer needs.

Unfortunately, the customer's scanner only displays special characters. I can't find an option to set the charset for output. LL_OPTION_SAVE_PROJECT_IN_UTF8 seems to have no effect. I also tried to set LL_OPTION_CODEPAGE to no avail.

How can the QR code be output as UTF-8?

Comment: Probably you're trying to print the Swiss Invoice QR-Code? I heard that question before for this very application. I will paste an answer with code for this scenario below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QR code itself has no fixed encoding. You may try to set the ECI using

```
LL.Core.LlXSetParameter(LlExtensionType.Barcode, "QRCode", "ECI", "0000026");
```

Depending on the scanner type this might help or not. In order to make sure to UTF-8 encode the contents you should pass them byte-by-byte - this circumvents any problems between the passing and rendering. A designer extension function that handles this job would be wired up like this:

[image: Designer Function]

The evaluation code would read:

```
private void designerFunction1_EvaluateFunction(object sender, EvaluateFunctionEventArgs e)
{
    string input = e.Parameter1.ToString();

    var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(input);
    StringBuilder barcodeContent = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in utfBytes)
    {
        barcodeContent.AppendFormat("~d{0:000}", b);
    }
    e.ResultValue = barcodeContent.ToString();
    e.ResultType = LlParamType.String;
}
```

Then use EncodeAsUTF8 for your barcode's content and your should be fine.

Comment: Starting with version 28, there's a built-in Designer function UTF8Encode$ that does the trick.